# Differentiate keydown on a HTML table row from a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Bootstrap HTML table where I need to detect when the delete key has been pressed at the row level and when at the cell level. Each cell has an Id. All javascript code is based on ES6 classes.

I'm setting the event handler as:

```
$('#footable').on('keydown',this.onKeyDown.bind(this));

onKeyDown(event){

}
```

This event gets fired whenever a key is pressed at the row level or at the cell level, however I'm not able to identify at what level it was fired. If I traverse the event data I always get the attributes of the row (id, class, etc and the entire row inner html). I have tried setting the event handler with selectors at the cell level, adding a standard class attribute E.g `'fooclass'` to each cell and attaching the event to the class but the event handler doesn't get fired: `$('[class*=fooclass]').on('keydown',this.onKeyDown.bind(this));`

Is there an option to differentiate this by using the .on method of JQUERY? Or any other option?

Comment: Each row is made of cells, how can you have a row click without a cell event?

Comment: The cell events are fired once the 'keydown' event is set through .on.

Comment: Rows are made of cells ok....how do you differentiate between the two?

Comment: @NarenMurali that's exactly what I want to know

Comment: add a cell that specifies row operations, other cells will have default cell behaviour!

Comment: @NarenMurali you mean with a button or any other control embedded in a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I was saying. You can simply add a first row, which can define row level events and other cells work for row events.

Simply see the difference, when the delete key is pressed on the input element on the first cell of the row and all other cells in the row!

```js
$("#test tr td:first").on("keydown", function(event){
 if(event.which == 46) alert("delete is pressed at row level");
});

$("#test tr td:not(:first)").on("keydown", function(event){
 if(event.which == 46) alert("delete is pressed at cell level");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <th>row</th>
    <th>cell</th>
    <th>cell</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice one, I did a little change to capture in the first column the row level events.  $("#test tr td:first-child").on("keydown", function(event){
 if(event.which == 46) alert("delete is pressed at row level");
});  

$("#test tr td:not(:first-child)").on("keydown", function(event){
 if(event.which == 46) alert("delete is pressed at cell level");
});

Comment: @JohnAngel Cool hope your issue is solved completely!